custom rule for SonarQube in Java : null check for switch statement
I am writing a custom rule for SonarQube in Java. I want to implement the rule that "When the variable type in the parentheses of a switch statement is String and this variable is an external parameter, a null check is required." Anyone has done that before? I failed to find a similar one in github. Thanks.
class AvoidSwitchNullRule{
    public void aMethod(String a){
        switch (a){ // Noncompliant {{When the variable type in the parentheses of a switch statement is String and this variable is an external parameter, a null check is required.}}
            case "1":{
                System.out.println(1);
                break;
            } case "2":{
                System.out.println(2);
                break;
            } default:{
                System.out.println("default");
            }
        }
    }

    public void bMethod(String a) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(a)){
            return;
        }
        switch (a){ // Compliant
            case "1":{
                System.out.println(1);
                break;
            } case "2":{
                System.out.println(2);
                break;
            } default:{
                System.out.println("default");
            }
        }
    }
}

The above is my example, the below is my rule. Obviously it's long before finished.
@Rule(key = "AvoidSwitchNullRule")
public class AvoidSwitchNullRule extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {
    @Override
    public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit() {
        return Arrays.asList(Tree.Kind.SWITCH_STATEMENT);
    }


    @Override
    @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
    public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
        SwitchStatementTree switchStatementTree = (SwitchStatementTree) tree;
        IdentifierTree identifierTree = (IdentifierTree) switchStatementTree.expression();

        if(identifierTree.symbolType().is("java.lang.String") && identifierTree.name().isEmpty()) {
            this.context.reportIssue(this,tree, "Switch Parameter must not be null");
        }
    }
}


private boolean isParameter(IdentifierTree identifierTree) {
    Symbol symbol = identifierTree.symbol();
    MethodTree methodTree = (MethodTree) Objects.requireNonNull(symbol.owner()).declaration();

    return symbol.owner().isMethodSymbol() && methodTree.parameters().stream()
            .anyMatch(param -> param.simpleName().toString().equals(identifierTree.name()));
}

private boolean hasNullCheckBefore(SwitchStatementTree switchStatementTree, String variableName) {
    BlockTree parentBlock = (BlockTree) switchStatementTree.parent();
    for (StatementTree statement : parentBlock.body()) {
        if (statement.equals(switchStatementTree)) {
            break;
        }
        if (statement.is(Tree.Kind.IF_STATEMENT)) {
            IfStatementTree ifStatement = (IfStatementTree) statement;
            // StringUtils.isEmpty(b)
            if(ifStatement.condition() instanceof MethodInvocationTree){
                MethodInvocationTree condition = (MethodInvocationTree) ifStatement.condition();
                if(condition.methodSelect() instanceof MemberSelectExpressionTree){
                    MemberSelectExpressionTree expressionTree = (MemberSelectExpressionTree) condition.methodSelect();
                    if(expressionTree.expression() instanceof IdentifierTree){
                        IdentifierTree identifierTree = (IdentifierTree) expressionTree.expression();
                        IdentifierTree identifierTree1 = expressionTree.identifier();
                        return ("StringUtils".equals(identifierTree.name()) && "isEmpty".equals(identifierTree1.name()));
                    }
                }
            }
            // c==null || null==c
            if (ifStatement.condition() instanceof BinaryExpressionTree) {
                BinaryExpressionTree binaryExpression = (BinaryExpressionTree) ifStatement.condition();
                if (("==").equals(binaryExpression.operatorToken().text()) || ("!=").equals(binaryExpression.operatorToken().text())) {
                    ExpressionTree leftOperand = binaryExpression.leftOperand();
                    ExpressionTree rightOperand = binaryExpression.rightOperand();
                    return (leftOperand.is(Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER) && ((IdentifierTree) leftOperand).name().equals(variableName) &&
                            rightOperand.is(Tree.Kind.NULL_LITERAL) && "null".equals(((LiteralTree) rightOperand).value())) ||
                            (rightOperand.is(Tree.Kind.IDENTIFIER) && ((IdentifierTree) rightOperand).name().equals(variableName) &&
                                    leftOperand.is(Tree.Kind.NULL_LITERAL) && "null".equals(((LiteralTree) leftOperand).value()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
